# Is there possibility to dynamicly pass user-defined variable (key = value) to terraform module?

Tags: terraform

There is resource:

```
resource "resource_name" "foo" {
  name        = "test"
  
  config {
    version = 14

    resources {
      disk_type_id       = "network-ssd"
    }

    postgresql_config = {
      enable_parallel_hash              = true
    }
  }
}
```

I need a module which accepts optional user variables in "postgresql_config". There can be many such variables.

I tried next:

**variables.tf**

```
variable "postgresql_config" {
  description = "User defined for postgresql_config"
  type = list(object({
  # key1 = value1
  # ...
  # key50 = value50
  }))
}

variable "config" {
  description = "for dynamic block 'config' "
  type = list(object({
    version                   = number
  }))
  default = [{
    version                   = 14
  }]
}

variable "resources" {
  description = "for dynamic block 'resources' "
  type = list(object({
    disk_type_id       = string
  }))
  default = [{
    disk_type_id       = "network-hdd"
  }]
}
```

**module/postgresql/main.tf**

```
resource "resource_name" "foo" {
  name        = "test"
  
  dynamic "config" {
    for_each = var.config
    content {
      version                   = config.value["version"]

      dynamic "resources" {
        for_each = var.resources
        content {
          disk_type_id       = resources.value["disk_type_id"]
        }
      }
      
      # problem is here
      postgresql_config = {
        for_each = var.postgresql_config
        each.key = each.value
      }

    }
}
```

**example/main.tf**

```
module "postgresql" {
  source = "../module/postgresql"

  postgresql_config = [{
    auto_explain_log_buffers = true
    log_error_verbosity = "LOG_ERROR_VERBOSITY_UNSPECIFIED"
    max_connections                   = 395
    vacuum_cleanup_index_scale_factor = 0.2
  }]
```

That is, I understand that I need to use "dynamic", but it can only be applied to the block "config" and the nested block "resource_name".

How can I pass values for "postgresql_config" from main.tf to module? Of course, my example with `for_each = var.postgresql_config` doesn't work, but I hope this way to give an idea of what I need.

Or does terraform have no such option to use custom variables dynamically at all, and all of them must be specified explicitly?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1):

from what I understand , you are trying to create a map dynamically for your resource postgres_config.

I would recommend using a for expression to solve that problem.

However, I think your problem lies in how you have defined variables for your module . You might run into a problem if your postgress_config list has multiple configs in it because that config can only take a map by the looks of it.

have a look at the following documentation:

this one is for how to define your variables

https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks#multi-level-nested-block-structures

for expressions

https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/for

my solution for your config problem ,would be something like this assuming that the postgres_config list has one element all the time:

```
      # problem is here
      postgresql_config = var.postgresql_config[0]
```